# What's the difference between "think of" and "make of"?

Tags: meaning, difference

For example:
"What do you think of this book?" and "What do you make of this book?"
"I don't know what to think of him?" and "I don't know what to make of him?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Think of" is asking for an opinion.  That could be quite simple "I think it's good", for example.

"Make of" is asking for an interpretation. It implies that the person asking the question is having trouble understanding something.

> I'm trying to read about Kant, and I'm finding it hard to understand. You've studied philosophy,  what do you make of this book?

There is a related saying "I can't make head or tails of (something)" which means I can't understand it at all.